# Creating row combinations (dyads) with a condition

Tags: python, pandas, loops, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I have the following database. Agreement_id represents the agreement. If two firms have the same agreement_id, it means that they have signed an agreement. The first and second rows have agreements_id = 1. The 3rd, 4th, 5th and 6th rows have agreement_id = 2 which means these 4 firms have entered the agreements.

```
ID  agreement_id firm                          firm_id  year
1   1            RMC Group PLC                 74961D   1980
2   1            Lafarge Asland SA             50590P   1980
3   2            Cable & Wireless Communicati  12682P   1981
4   2            Portugal Telecom SA           737273   1981
5   2            CITIC 1616 Holdings Ltd       17339L   1981
6   2            Macau Post                    1A7458   1981
7   3            Zarubezhneft'                 98914R   1981
8   3            PetroVietnam                  71675K   1981
9   4            Suntory Ltd                   86787Q   1981
10  4            Anheuser-Busch Cos Inc        035229   1981
11  5            Daimler-Benz Aerospace AG     23384K   1981
12  5            Finmeccanica SpA              318027   1981
13  6            Canadian Oil Sands Ltd        13643E   1982
14  6            Imperial Oil Ltd              453038   1982
15  6            Suncor Energy Inc-Certain Asts3A3559   1982
16  6            Nexen Inc-Chemical Division   05829M   1982
17  6            Mocal Energy Ltd              55441R   1982
18  6            Murphy Oil Corp               626717   1982
19  6            China Petroleum & Chemical    16941R   1982
```

All I want to do it build dyads and put unique firm_ids (firms which have signed a contract - same agreement_id - stands in the same row)  into two separate columns. In other words I need row combinations for the same agreement_id's. For example:

```
ID agreement_id firm_id_1 firm_id_2  year
1  1            74961D    50590P     1980
2  2            12682P    737273     1981
3  2            12682P    17339L     1981
4  2            12682P    1A7458     1981
5  2            737273    17339L     1981
6  2            737273    1A7458     1981
7  2            17339L    1A7458     1981
```

I think here the most difficult task is to transform multilateral agreements into dyads.

The last part of this question is that I want use firm_id_2 as a focal firm, in other words use the second firm as a focal firm (duplicate each row and change firm_id_1's and firm_id_2's values). Here is the output:

```
    ID agreement_id firm_id_1 firm_id_2  year
    1  1            74961D    50590P     1980
    2  1            50590P    74961D     1980
    3  2            12682P    737273     1981
    4  2            737273    12682P     1981
    5  2            12682P    17339L     1981
    6  2            17339L    12682P     1981
```

- In the end i will have 2 rows for agreement 1 and 12 for agreement (2 * 6 original dyads).
- (note: Same for all dyads)
- (note: I use Python in jupyter notebooks)

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `pcusip = agreements['PCUSIP']`
`df = agreements.set_index("PCUSIP")`
`cc = list(combinations(pcusip,2))`

This codes finds combination between row, but there are two problems to fix:
**1**. _It gives all possible combination, but I need combinations of rows which have the same agreement_id__
**2.** _It drops all other columns, but I wanna keep year, firm_id and agreement_id_

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem using R:

```
colnames(df) <- c("X", "ID","Agreement", "Firm", "FirmID", "Year") # assigning column names to dta_out

dta_inp <- df

# merging dta_inp with itself on agreement and year

dta_out <- merge(dta_inp, dta_inp, by.x = c("Agreement", "Year"), by.y = c("Agreement", "Year")) 

# determining values for which FirmID.x == FirmID.y

dta_out <- cbind(dta_out, out = (dta_out$FirmID.x == dta_out$FirmID.y)) 

# removing values for which FirmID.x == FirmID.y

dta_out <- dta_out[dta_out$out == FALSE, ][,-5]
```

After dropping unnecessary columns and sorting by agreements:

```
Agreement   Year    FirmID.X    Firm.y                           FirmID.y

        1   1980    74961D      Lafarge Asland SA                50590P
        1   1980    50590P      RMC Group PLC                    74961D
        2   1981    12682P      Portugal Telecom SA              737273
        2   1981    12682P      CITIC 1616 Holdings Ltd          17339L
        2   1981    12682P      Macau Post                       1A7458
        2   1981    737273      Cable & Wireless Communicati     12682P
        2   1981    737273      CITIC 1616 Holdings Ltd          17339L
        2   1981    737273      Macau Post                       1A7458
        2   1981    17339L      Cable & Wireless Communicati     12682P
        2   1981    17339L      Portugal Telecom SA              737273
        2   1981    17339L      Macau Post                       1A7458
        2   1981    1A7458      Cable & Wireless Communicati     12682P
        2   1981    1A7458      Portugal Telecom SA              737273
        2   1981    1A7458      CITIC 1616 Holdings Ltd          17339L
```

Github link: https://gist.github.com/farid-mammadaliyev/2163b206435f71574b4c54966d18539c